# Installation of Django on ubuntu16.04 using pip faces error

Tags: django, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I was trying to install Django1.10 on my ubuntu 16.04 using `pip install Django==1.10`. Now I'm facing an error which I think is related to directories of installation path but I don't know how to get through. Here is the error:

- > Exception:
  >   Traceback (most recent call last):
  >   File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
  >   status = self.run(options, args)
  >   File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
  >   prefix=options.prefix_path,
  >   File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
  >   **kwargs
  >   File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
  >   self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  >   File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
  >   isolated=self.isolated,
  >   File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
  >   clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  >   File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
  >   ensure_dir(destdir)
  >   File "/home/atenagm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
  >   os.makedirs(path)
  >   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
  >   mkdir(name, mode)
  >   OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.dist-info'

Can anybody tell me what I should do to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are install django on UBUNTU then you have to use `sudo pip install Django==1.10`.
`sudo` gives administrative rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running pip as sudo is not the best of choices. That is like giving superuser access to an external application. Rather try this first:

```
pip install --user django==1.11
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need super user privilege to install a package globally. So append `sudo` before your command.

```
sudo pip install Django==1.10
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know why I could not figure the problem out myself.